# usage of "renowned"

Tags: word-usage

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/renowned) gives this definition about "renowned"

> famous for something

Cambridge Dictionary also gives these examples

> The region is renowned **for** its outstanding natural beauty.
>
> Marco Polo is a renowned explorer/is renowned **as** an explorer.

I guess I understand all the content above. Could some help to double check the use in the following sentences?

> Cambridge, Massachusetts is renowned **as** the home of Harvard University and the Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)
>
> Cambridge, Massachusetts is renowned **for** Harvard University and the Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)

I am aware that they are different situations which need different prepositions, though I cannot state the rules out clearly.

Could someone please give a hint about **the rules/conventions of it**? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "renowned as" requires equating the subject and predicate.
Cambridge is famous because it **is** the home...
So, Cambridge **=** home

The phrase "renowned for" means "famous because of".
Cambridge is famous **because of** Harvard etc.

It's a structurally different way of saying the same thing.